# Why was my RDS instance modification un-done?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Recently I downgraded a client's RDS instance from medium to small. I looked in on it today to find that it had somehow reverted back to a medium instance. I did not do this nor does anyone else have access to our instances...

Could this have happened during some system restore or other fail-safe type of operation? Or is it just a glitch?

If it is part of expected behavior, is there some way to alter the configuration so in the future any restores/whatever will instantiate as my chosen size (small)?

Comment: Anything is possible, but nothin like this is expected.  You didn't mention the server engine but for MySQL, for example, `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'UPTIME';` will tell you that the instance class has not been changed for *at least* as long as the amount of time shown.  My first assumption would be that if you didn't check this after changing the instance class, the change might not have happened, though that's almost as unreasonable as the reversion to the old settings.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I actually watched the entire modification go through originally and watched the monitors for the first day or 2. It was properly labeled as a small instance and a higher % of CPU was being consumed as expected. Since everything was stable & load was fine, I stopped monitoring. It was only a couple weeks later when I checked in on it that I noticed it had now reverted. I'm thinking about telling my client to call up & make some noise to try get that $$ back, as this is a horribly poor business practice if it was their error... And yes it's MySQL, I'll check that status.